# Blinking dots/pixels python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have a mapping programs with many objects on the screen and I trying to find a way to change things up a bit to make it easier to see everything.  Using different colors only works so so as there are only so many colors you can use/detect as to which color is which.  The idea came up to change a standard object into a blinking object so it would change things up/draw attention to itself.

With the zoom levels that are preferred with the way the program is being setup, trying to use different shapes just doesn't really seem feasible.  So it has all come back to the same blinking object idea.

I have seen here on SO the concept of two screens and switching in between them, simple enough to do.  The trouble is how do you do that and still have the program usable otherwise(being able to move around the map with the map scrollable vertically/horizontally, being able to scroll across a point and have it pop up underlying data in a side window, etc).  I still need full control of the rest of the program instead of having it tied up in a timer loop.  The switching between screens would need to occur 'in the background'.  How do you do that?  I'm totally ignorant here so I'm not even sure what to search for.

If I understand what one of the comments is asking??? I'm using Tkinter and Python 3.5.

I'm using the following code to add the dots to screen and to store the dots so I can check the current tag to know when I have scrolled the mouse across a dot so I can bring up the underlying data in a side window.

```
z = self.canvas.create_line(pix1x, pix1y, pix1x+4, pix1y+4, activewidth="10.0", fill = '', width = 5, state = 'disabled')
self.srvloc.append((z,x))
```

This is done initially at runtime of the program and then when I click on the checkbutton for the certain service to come up that changes the color...

```
self.canvas.itemconfig(self.srvloc[x][0], fill='#0000ff', state = 'normal')
```

to both 'activate' and turn the pixel blue, in this particular case.  Naturally this is going through the entire database and looking for the those that match the required criteria.  When I click off the the checkbutton it turns the dot back to fill = '', state = 'disabled'

Not sure about the after loop if that would work or not.  It has to be something that basically makes it flash but does so in the background with the rest of the normal program uninterrupted.

Comment: Just updated it, I think I gave what you was asking for...Tkinter and Python 3.5.

Comment: Yup, that's helpful! I added it as a tag to your question as well.

Comment: in order to be able to give a useful answer we need to know a bit more about what you currently have. you say you have many objects, are these tk widgets or objects on a canvas? if they are ordinary widgets then most of them have a `flash` method, if they are drawn on a canvas then you could do something with an `after` loop that alternates the tagged object between two colours at a set interval, but we need to know what you have, preferably a stripped down sample code to base our answers on

Comment: Objects drawn on a canvas.  5x5 pixels that mark a location on a map made in tkinter.  I'll add the line of code that puts the dots on the screen in just a second.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a blinking object the most easy way is to use an `after()` loop.

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas
import time
root = Tk()
# you can do geometry and title if you want
def func():
      c.itemconfig(line, state="normal")
      time.sleep(intervalInSec)
      c.itemconfig(line, state="hidden")
      root.after(intervalInMs, func)
c = Canvas(root, width=800, height=500) # you can change height and width
line = c.create_line(0, 0, 400, 250, fill="", state="hidden")
root.after(intervalInMs, func)
```

This should work just fine.
If you want you could check the state of the line to avoid using `time.sleep`.